# linux sudoers not work on command `su`

Tags: linux, permissions, sudo, sudoers

I want to disable command `sudo` and `su` for user in group `staff`.

So I put this in `/etc/sudoers`:

```
%staff ALL=ALL, !/usr/bin/sudo,!/usr/bin/su
```

But I found, only `sudo` work, `su` still work for user in group `staff`.

I also tried this:

```
%staff ALL=ALL, !/usr/bin/sudo
%staff ALL=ALL, !/usr/bin/su
```

Still, works for `sudo` but not `su`.

How can I fix this?

Comment: If you block `sudo` in `sudoers` then you will block `sudo sudo …` command. If you block `su` in `sudoers` then you will block `sudo su …`. Is this what you want to do? To block `su …` you cannot use `sudoers` because `sudoers` has nothing to do with `su`. If `sudo` is called then `sudoers` matters. If not, then `sudoers` doesn't matter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`su` is not `sudo`... they are two separate tools with very different behaviours.

`su` will not be influenced by `/etc/sudoers` because that file is unrelated to it.

- `su` - requires the root password, and allows users to authenticate "*as*" root as if they had tried to login using the username `root`.
- `sudo` - allows the user to prove their own identity (e.g: by re-entering their own password) and gain root privileges for a specific task (or privileges of another user).

If you want do "*disable*" `su`, (probably not advisable), then you'll need to either remove its execute flag(s), or remove it from your system.

Why is `su` a problem? Does your `root` account have a password? (I don't know, but if it doesn't, then `su` might not prompt for authentication).

---

For clarity, `/etc/sudoers` influences the behaviour of commands are run with `sudo`, for example:

- `sudo ${cmd}`
- `sudo dd ...`
- `sudo su` - what you're blocking with `%staff ALL=ALL, !/usr/bin/su`
- `sudo sudo ...` - what you're blocking with `%staff ALL=ALL, !/usr/bin/sudo`

Comment: Yes, on my pc, `root` have password. So, `/etc/sudoers` file only works with command `sudo someting`, it can only control who can using `sudo someting` command. Is that right?

Comment: That's correct - `sudoers` controls the behaviour of `sudo ${cmd}`.

Answer (score 2):

You can't really "disallow" the use of `su`. However, in order to use that to gain root privilege, you'll need root's password.

Contrary, `sudo` allows you to gain root access simply by using your own credentials. Thus, this is something that you want to limit to respectively trustful users only (here: people in group `staff`).